# MySQL Connector / CharacterSet / two connections

Tags: python, mysql-connector, charset

I am facing a problem using python, mysql.connector (8.1.0) and trying to open 2 connections on 2 different servers:

If I run :

```
from mysql.connector import MySQLConnection

if __name__ in '__main__':
    
    # A
    try:
        c1 = MySQLConnection(
            host='host1',
            user='*',
            password='*',
            database='A'
        )
        c1.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        print('c1')
    
    # B
    try:
        c2 = MySQLConnection(
            host='host2',
            user='*',
            password='*',
            database='B'
        )
        c2.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        print('c2')
```

I got exception : `Character set 'utf8' unsupported` for c2

If I run only part B, it's Ok. It's as if something was set globally after the first connection.

any idea?

**EDIT:** Got it ! `CharacterSet.desc` is a class variable set at begining.

```
from mysql.connector import MySQLConnection as MySQLConnection
from mysql.connector.constants import CharacterSet

if __name__ in '__main__':

    desc = CharacterSet.desc.copy()

    try:
        c1 = MySQLConnection(
            host='host1',
            user='*',
            password='*',
            database='A'
        )
        c1.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        print('c1')

    CharacterSet.desc = desc

    try:
        c2 = MySQLConnection(
            host='host2',
            user='*',
            password='*',
            database='B'
        )
        c2.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        print('c2')
```

It works now

Comment: What happens if you run part B and then part A?

Comment: @StephenC It is ok if B then A

Comment: OK ... so that means that it is *also* something to do with the actual servers and databases and (I guess) their selected character sets and collations.  The next step would be to figure out what they are in each case.

Comment: @StephenC Thanks. Still can't understand why I can use B, B and A but not A and B.

Comment: If you can figure out what the database and server character sets are, that will be a start.  Also database server versions.  Basically, you need more information.

Comment: @snakecharmerb No 11.1.2 for c1 and 10.4.18 for c2. I didn't say it but it's MariaDB

Answer (score 0):

If both connections (c1 and c2) work fine when run separately but produce the "Character set 'utf8' unsupported for c2" error when run together, it's likely due to a compatibility issue with the character set configurations between the two connections. you may try below steps:

**Specify Character Set for Both Connections:** Explicitly specify the character set for both connections to ensure they use the same character set. For example, you can use 'utf8mb4' for both connections

```
c1 = MySQLConnection(
    host='host1',
    user='*',
    password='*',
    database='A',
    charset='utf8mb4'
)

c2 = MySQLConnection(
    host='host2',
    user='*',
    password='*',
    database='B',
    charset='utf8mb4'
)
```

**Use Separate Connection Instances:** Ensure that you are not inadvertently sharing a connection instance between the two connections (c1 and c2). Each connection should have its own separate instance.

Comment: "Use Separate Connection Instances" : That is not what I'm doing ?!

Comment: "Specify Character Set for Both Connections" : I'm not supposed to know them before connect

Comment: you can use *SHOW CHARACTER SET* to get character set.

Answer (score 0):

Both server are utf8mb4.

No real explanation why it works if B is in first but `mysql.connector` is totaly not safe for mariadb (I have read the opposite several times).

During the handcheck, first says it is 11.1.2-MariaDB (arch linux package) and second says 5.5.5-10.4.18-MariaDB (ubuntu package).

Connector try to get the version with:

```
regex_ver = re.compile(r"^(\d{1,2})\.(\d{1,2})\.(\d{1,3})(.*)")
```

And before exception, check is done and fail:

```
if charset in ("utf8", "utf-8") and cls.mysql_version >= (8, 0):
    charset = "utf8mb4"
```

So I am just moving to official MariaDB connector package...

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

This way works :

```
import os
from mysql.connector import MySQLConnection as MySQLConnection

if __name__ in '__main__':

    pid = os.fork()

    if pid == 0:
        try:
            c1 = MySQLConnection(
                host='host1',
                user='*',
                password='*',
                database='A'
            )

            with c1.cursor() as cursor:
                cursor.execute("SELECT 1, 'A'")
                print(cursor.fetchone())

            c1.close()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        finally:
            print('c1')

    else:
        try:
            c2 = MySQLConnection(
                host='host2',
                user='*',
                password='*',
                database='B'
            )

            with c2.cursor() as cursor:
                cursor.execute("SELECT 1, 'B'")
                print(cursor.fetchone())

            c2.close()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        finally:
            print('c2')
```

But I can't do that in a gui app.